# Using An Extra Table Instead Of Arrays - MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, join, foreign-keys

I have an image library where I wish to have the functionality for users to create boards from existing images in the MySQL database along certain themes. For instance they can create a board called 'London' and add photos of London that already exist in the library to that board.

In the boards table I intially couldn't work out how to store the images (effectively as an array) for each board, but having read some other answers it seems the best way to approach this is to create an additional table as well as the `boards` table?

There are currently tables that cover `images` and `users` (simplified below):

**users table**

```
+- id --+  username --+- 
|  36   |  Ted        |
|  37   |  James      |
```

**images table**

```
+- id ----+  filename -------+- file_extension -+-
|  1038   |  bigben          |  jpeg            |
|  1039   |  toweroflondon   |  jpeg            |
```

So, if I'm understanding this, I'll first have to create a boards table as per below

**boards table**

```
+- id -+ board_name -+- 
|  1   |  London     |
|  2   |  Trees      |
```

...and then an additional table that consists of purely foreign keys: the `id` and `board_name` from the `boards` table, and the `image_filename` and `file_extension` from my images table, and the `user_id` of the person that set up the board which is the `id` from the users table.

**images_boards table**

```
+- board_id -+ board_name -+- image_filename -+- file_extension -+- user_id -+-
|  1         |  London     |  bigben          |  jpeg            |   36      |
|  1         |  London     |  toweroflondon   |  jpeg            |   36      |
```

I'm struggling to get my head around this conceptually, it feels odd having a table made up of purely foreign keys, although this may well be perfectly acceptable / preferred solution in such a use case.

My question thus is - am I approaching this correctly ?

Comment: I would claim that the image_boards example needlessly duplicates data from other tables into the image_boards table... you really only need three columns based on what I perceive based on the information, so the FK would be acceptable/preferred. I would think image_boards (based on your 2 example rows) having board_id, image_id, user_id as columns would have the combinations of (1, 1038, 36) and (1, 1039, 36)?

Comment: Will you be gathering thousands of images?  Are the images being stored on disk or in the database?  Will web pages be pulling up the images?  Do you have "meta" info about the images other than the name and type -- such as size, origin. etc?  I ask these questions because the answers will have some impact on the details of the solution.

Comment: @RickJames Images are stored in folders (disk), filenames are actually generated by the Imagick PHP image library on upload (i used more readable ones in the question for obvious reasons), filename and file extension have their own columns in the images table of the database, as does image dimensions (px). Yes potentially many thousands of images. Only EXIF data store is the dimensions though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have `board_id` and `board_name` in a table that maps those two together, do not also have both `board_id` and `board_name` in any other table.  Instead, use only `board_id` in other tables.

Meanwhile, the `boards` table will have `board_id` and `board_name` (each indexed), plus any attributes about a "board".

`images_boards` will have a `board_id` and `image_id`; nothing else is required.  And have two indexes on this many-to-many table:  `PRIMARY KEY(board_id, image_id)` and `INDEX(image_id, board_id)`.  There is no need for a separate "id" for that table.

You also mention `user_id` -- Is it associated with the board?  Or with the image?  Or is it really another dimension to the association?  If the latter, then it is OK (though unusual) to have that as a third column.

Comment: Thanks Rick. The `user_id` in this context will be associated with the boards. The board has a title and creator on show i.e. 'London, by John Doe'. The name will be a link which goes to the main profile page of who created the board.

Comment: @paulo_cam - So, it is 1:many.  That is, one user can have many boards, but not vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

A board can contain several images, and an image can be added to several boards. That's a typical example of a ["many-to-many"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)) relationship in a data model.

So your approach is good, but as Paul wrote in his comment you don't have to duplicate the content of the `images` table into the `image_boards` one. You only need a `image_id` column in it instead.

These keys are only used to store the relationship between all these entities. Then your queries are going to join the related tables to retrieve the additional information needed from each entity.

Also if you put `user_id` in this table, this should mean that a board that has been created by a user can be populated with images by other users. If it's not the case, then the `user_id` column should be in the `boards` table only. It would be useless to repeat it in every board/image relationship.

Finally, you will have to set a primary key for the rows of your `images_boards` table. There are generally two approaches for that:

- Either you create a new auto incremented column that would be the id of this relationship (for instance `images_boards_id`).
- Or you can use existing columns to compose a unique combination that can be used as a primary key. In your case if an image can't be added more than once within the same board, then the combination of `board_id` and `image_id` can be used to compose a primary key.

Answer (score 0):

When structuring relational databases it's usually best to follow some level of normalisation. This makes it's easier to add more tables and restructure the tables. Read more about the different normalisation levels here in Wikipedia for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

So in this case you would only need the foreign keys in the images_boards table.

Then you just join the tables when you want to fetch the data. Example that fetches the data for one board if the images_boards has the following columns: board_id, image_id and user_id.

```
SELECT boards.id AS board_id, board_name, images.id AS image_id, image_filename, file_extension, users.id AS user_id, username
FROM your_schema.images_boards
INNER JOIN your_schema.images ON (images_boards.image_id = images.id)
INNER JOIN your_schema.boards ON (images_boards.board_id = boards.id)
INNER JOIN your_schema.users ON (images_boards.user_id = users.id)
WHERE board_id = x
```